# Как узнать размер динамического массива

Tags: c++

Как узнать размер динамического массива.

```
char * word = "whatever"
```

при вызову 
    sizeof 
или как пишут в интернете

```
sizeof(word)/sizeof(word[0]);
```

всегда возвращается 4 при любом слове. А что за причина такая что можно легко узнать размер в байтах значения, а вот размер массива так сложно узнать. Я пришел из Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас там не массив, а указатель на строку. Программа у вас 32-битная, поэтому и возвращается размер 4 байта, то есть размер указателя в 32-битной программе. Определите массив как

```
char word[] = "whatever";
int sz = sizeof(word) / sizeof(word[0]);
```

`sz` будет равно 9 (8 букв плюс завершающий 0).

Еще, кстати, замечу, что `sizeof(word[0]` равен единице - это размер символа ASCII. Так что формулу в данном случае можно немного упростить.

И еще замечу, что массив у вас никакой не динамический, а самый что ни на есть статический.

Comment: А могу ли я массив использовать если слово приходит снаружи в рантайме? может это стоило бы указать в вопросе

Comment: @J Mas, не понял что значит "приходит снаружи в рантайме". Передается как аргумент функции, что ли? В C/C++ нельзя передать массив в функцию. Даже если формальный параметр объявлен как массив, передается все равно указатель. В C++ с STL можно передать контейнеры array<> или vector<>, которые  представляют соответственно статический и динамический массивы.

Answer (score 1):

В данном объявлении

```
char * word = "whatever";
```

объявляется не объект массива, а объект указателя, который указывает на первый символ строкового литерала. И размер указателя фиксирован независимо от того, указывает ли он на скалярный объект, или на первый элемент массива.

Заметьте, что в C++ строковые литералы имеют тип константных символьных массивов. Поэтому указатель, который указывает на строковый литерал, должен объявляться с квалификатором `const`:

```
const char * word = "whatever";
```

Чтобы объявить именно массив, нужно написать

```
char word[] = "whatever";
```

Тогда вы, действительно, можете использовать выражение `sizeof( word ) / sizeof( *word )` для подсчета элементов в массиве.

В случае массивов, или указателей на массивы, содержащие строки, вы также можете использовать стандартную функцию strlen, для определения, сколько символов в строке (исключая завершающий ноль).

Например,

```
#include <cstring>

//...

char word[100] = "whatever";
size_t n = std::strlen( word ); // n = 8
```

или

```
#include <cstring>

//...

const char *word = "whatever";
size_t n = std::strlen( word ); // n = 8
```